# reshaping numpy array from (1000,1000,3) to (3,1000,1000) and back

Tags: python, arrays

I have a numpy array with the shape (3,1000,1000) and I have had to change it to (1000,1000,3) for some image processing. I now need to reshape back to (3,1000,1000) preserving the original places, but am unable to figure out how to do it. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1] * 1000000).reshape(1000,1000)
arr2 = np.array([2] * 1000000).reshape(1000,1000)
arr3 = np.array([3] * 1000000).reshape(1000,1000)

arr_list = list((arr1,arr2,arr3))
arr = np.array(arr_list).reshape(3,1000,1000)
arr_d = np.dstack(arr_list)
```

`arr` is the original shape of the array, while `arr_d` is the shape I needed for the image processing.
Essentially, each of the original 2-D matrices in `arr` are a column in `arr_d`. Now I need to get back from `arr_d` to `arr`, preserving the values.

Comment: Here is my somewhat klugey answer. `arr_list_new = [arr_d[:,:,i] for i in range(0,arr_d.shape[2])]
arr_new = np.array(arr_list_new).reshape(3,1000,1000)`. Feel free to show a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's as easy as transposing arr_d

```
>>> np.array_equal(arr, arr_d.T)
True
```

Comment: thanks. That is the best answer for sure and I would haven't ever thought of transposing in three dimensions. I am limited to a 2D world.

Comment: There is also the verbose `np.transpose(arr_d, [2, 0, 1])` where you pass the axes permutation explicitly. It might be easier for a reader to understand what the code does if you  are not familiar with how `.T` behaves on `> 2`-dimensional arrays.